# Inline onclick undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am editing a site which has an anchor tag with an onclick attribute.  The event calls a modal which displays details of a customer's order.  The link is not working in IE.  The function callResendEmailService is undefined, but this same piece of code is working in Chrome and Firefox.  What is needed for it to work in IE?

```
<a onclick="callResendEmailService(orderId);"href="javascript:void(0)">Click here</a>

function callResendEmailService(orderId){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {orderId },
            dataType:"text",
            url : contextPath+'resendVoucherEmail.htm',
            success: function(dataReturn, textStatus, xhr){
                if(dataReturn=='error'){
                alert("Error in sending email");}
                else{
                showEmailConfirmationOverlay();}
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
               alert("Error in sending email");
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Try wrapping your Javascript in `<script>`  `</script>`.  Might help.

Comment: Does IE raise any other errors? Your snippet uses [ES6+ features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) – `data: {orderId }` – and [IE doesn't support those](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions) (the only Microsoft browser that does is Edge).

Comment: @JaromandaX It has to be defined before it's called, it doesn't have to be defined before it's referenced.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Barmar there are no other errors in the console.

Comment: in IE there will be an error because as a previous comment says, you are using an ES2015+ feature ...  `data: {orderId }` ... will need to be `data: {orderId:orderId }` to be **valid syntax** in IE. I'm surprised you are not getting a console error when loading the page about a missing `:`

Comment: I see a markup error.... inline events must be quoted and separated from other attribute tags by space(s). sb.

<a onclick="callResendEmailService(orderId);" href="javascript:void(0)">Click here</a>

Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages"... save changes.... 
To debug web pages (all dev tools), you must have selected "Break on unhandled errors" or "Break on all errors" and the dev tool MUST be visible (don't close it while testing). Normally (all browsers) ignore any scripting errors (do not halt execution or write messages to the dev console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
        data: {orderId },
```

to:

```
        data: {orderId: orderId },
```

The syntax you're using is an Ecmascript 6 feature, which isn't available in IE.